# Expression to function

Tags: r, function, type-conversion, expression

I'm trying to solve an equation using `uniroot()` but before that I must differentiate an expression.

I create the expression, then differentiate it with `D()` but I have no clue how to return said expression to a function I can take the root of.

So far I have:

```
eq<-expression((w^2)*3+((1-w)^2)*2.5+2*w*(1-w)*0.9)
f<-D(eq, name="w")
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (Thanks to flodel for the useful comment):

```
g = function(w) eval(f)
uniroot(g, c(0,1000))
```

Comment: or just `g <- function(w) eval(f)`